# Sql Query to get single values from group of values seperated by comma

Tags: sql-server

i have a string value '4578,6978,6578,987', now my requirement all comma's in the string should not come in resultset and should display like 4578 6978 6578 987

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=sql%20server%20split%20string)

Comment: have you looked into `REPLACE` function?